GlShaderProgram для Media3 Transformer для сохранения частоты кадров с помощью SpeedChangeEffect (скорость < 1)
Пытаюсь использовать рендер видео от Media3 Transformer.
Сталкивался ли кто-то с проблемой отрисовки дополнительных кадров с помощью GlShaderProgram?
Из коробки есть FrameDropEffect, но он используется для снижения фпс. Кейс состоит в том, чтобы использовать SpeedChangeEffect для замедления видео, но сохранить значение фпс исходного видео. Что-то похожее на правду примерно получается, но результат зависит от значения самой скорости.

А где вы возьмёте дополнительные кадры? Если копировать существующие, то визуально это будет выглядеть точно так же, как и без этого "повышения" ФПС

@woesss, да, я знаю, что будет тоже самое видео, но требования таковы. И да, нужно копировать существующие
